# MVC5 - Qual a forma correta de se trabalhar com o MVC no caso de retorno de dados de um grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

Possuo um modelo com 4 campos que após um filtro exibe um grid com X registros na mesma pagina (VIEW).

Gostaria de saber a melhor maneira de se retornar os dados do"grid" em questão para o controller?

Exemplo simplificado (Model):

```
    namespace WebApplication1.Models 
    {
        public class modeloTST
        {
            [Display(Name = "Informe a Nome:")]     
            public string Nome { get; set; }     //filtro

            public List<classeTST> lstITENS{ get; set;}  //exibicao em grid
        }
    }
```

Comment: Depende muito do que você quer fazer. Se for somente para exibir os dados da lista na View, você pode fazer uma View tipada e realizar um laço de repetição no razor.